# Jekyll site hosted on Firebase- "This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory

Tags: firebase, jekyll

Very new here. I've got a static Jekyll site hosted through Firebase, navbar links show this error:

Page Not Found
This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

Site viewed on local server has absolutely no issues with nav links, only the deployed site. index.html seems fine, firebase.json seems set up ok. Any ideas?